# Why does Resharper Think This Code is Unreachable

Tags: c#, .net-core, resharper

As I am coding, I noticed that ReSharper (v2019.1.1) thinks that part of my code is unreachable:

[image: Unreachable Code]

I have learned to trust ReSharper, so I build a test harness to see what was going on:

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> scopeList = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> customFields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var mainScope = new Scope();
    var subScope = new Scope();
    subScope.Parent = mainScope;

    dynamic currentState = new Tuple<String, int>("bob", 1565);
    mainScope.State = currentState;
    subScope.State = "Hello";

    WriteScopes(subScope, scopeList, customFields);

    Console.WriteLine(customFields);
    Console.WriteLine(scopeList);
}

public void WriteScopes(Scope scope, List<string> scopeList, Dictionary<string, string> customFields)
{
    var loopScope = scope;

    while (loopScope != null)
    {
        var loopState = loopScope.State;
        if (loopState == null) continue;
        if (loopState is (string name, var value))
        {
            customFields.Add(name, value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            scopeList.Add(loopState.ToString());
        }

        loopScope = loopScope.Parent;
    }
}

public class Scope
{
    public Scope Parent { get; set; }
    public object State { get; set; }
}
```

When I ran my test, it seems that the "unreachable code" is being executed by the `"Hello"` string.  But as I said above, I have learned to trust ReSharper, so I am wondering what is going on?

**Why does ReSharper think that code is unreachable?**

Comment: I'm writing the code of WriteScopes in [Imgurmy VS](https://i.imgur.com/kpCTNxV.png), but I don't seem the message (I have Resharper enabled and c# 8 features enabled and my version of RS is 2019.3.4)

Comment: Heuristically means possibly, your code is possibly unreachable. "Unreachable code detected" is what you get when resharper is sure that your code is ain't going to get executed. It is probably resharper out smarting itself.

Comment: @Marlonchosky - Based off you comment I upgraded to the latest version (v2020.1.2). Once I did, the section of code was not longer listed as unreachable.  If you would like to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Vaccano done!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, exactly I don't know why the code is marked as unreachable, but in [my VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0c5y.png) with ReSharper 2019.3.4, I'm not seeing the message. It probably be a bug in the tool.

Comment: To any who see this later, this issue was fixed for me by upgrading to ReSharper 2020.1.2.